# Change mod-rewrite rules to route specific file requests to index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a default rule for my PHP framework in .htaccess file that routes all requests except specific files to index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]
```

For example, if I have site-specific images in /images folder, request **foo.com/images/name.jpg** will be processed directly to filesystem.

But I need a special behavior for URLs with specific path, f.e. /image. So requests like **foo.com/image/name.jpg** should also be routed to index.php...

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule .*\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar|gz)$ /index.php [L]`

Comment: Thank you!!! Could you tell me in short what exactly you have changed in this rule processing?

Comment: @SantaFox Only thing I really changed is `!` to `.*`.  I'm not sure what you think the `!` was supposed to do but the `.*` means any character 0 or more times followed by a `\.` (DOT) then followed by any of the extensions.  So it matches like `abc.jpg` or `abc123.png`.  Yours only matches `!.jpg`, `!.png`, etc.  If you like my answer, please click on the check mark next to it to accept it.